# En el controlador llamas a la interfaz del servicio o al servicio implementado?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Me surge la duda si tengo un servicio y su implementacion.

```
@Service
public class ClienteServiceImpl implements ClienteService {

@Autowired
ClienteRepository repositorio;

@Override
public List<Cliente> list() {
    return repositorio.findAll();
}

@Override
public Cliente get(Long id) {
    return repositorio.getById(id);
}

@Override
public Cliente post(Cliente input) {
    return repositorio.save(input);
}

}
```

en el controllador llamo a la interfaz a la implementacion o da igual?

```
@RestController
```

public class ClienteController {
@Autowired
ClienteService servicio;

Comment: Siempre siempre siempre llama a la interfaz en donde sea que vayas a consumir el servicio. El día de mañana haces una nueva implementación de tu servicio y tienes que cambiar el código en todos lados si no usas interfaces. Deja a Spring la responsabilidad de inyectar la implementación que hayas marcado, pero el controllador debe depender de una abstracción, no de una implementación concreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

su uso esta muy ligado al concepto de herencia y cumple el mismo principio que aplicamos al usar clases abstractas, lo que buscamos es establecer un mecanismo donde podamos compartir características comunes entre clases diferentes, además al igual que con clases abstractas nos aseguramos que los métodos y atributos solo están disponibles para las clases que las implementen..

Beneficios que nos aportan las interfaces:

1. Organizar el código.
2. Declarar constantes para todos las clases que las implementen.
3. Permitir el bajo acoplamiento entre los componentes.
4. Establecer relaciones entre clases.
5. Obligar a las clases a implementar métodos con una determinada firma.
6. Establecer contratos a futuro.
7. Son un soporte para la carencia de herencia múltiple que tiene Java.

Podemos dividir las funcionalidades de las interfaces en cuatro propiedades:

Abstracción

Una interfaz es como un contrato. El servicio que implementa una interfaz está obligado a ofrecer una serie de métodos con firmas bien definidas. Cualquier servicio que quiera cumplir con la interfaz tendrá que tener obligatoriamente un conjunto determinado de elementos. Esto te permite conectarte a diferentes servicios usando el mismo cliente.

Usabilidad

Si tu servicio implementa una interfaz, podrías reescribirlo completamente (o sustituirlo por otro distinto) y los clientes podrían seguir consumiendo tu servicio sin problemas. Ellos a lo sumo notarán diferencias en el rendimiento, pero poco más.

Seguridad

Una interfaz representa únicamente una declaración de intenciones. No aparece código por ninguna parte. Al exponer una interfaz no estás comprometiendo el código fuente del servicio.

Mantenimiento

Si un servicio expone una interfaz tu entorno de desarrollo puede verificar fácilmente que una nueva versión del servicio cumple (al menos) con los requisitos expuestos en la interfaz. Es una forma sencilla de automatizar un proceso que evita que se te olvide implementar parte de la funcionalidad. Esta característica suele mejorar el índice de mantenimiento de los proyectos.

Con todo esto, parece casi evidente que es una buena práctica exponer interfaces siempre que sea posible. Que un sistema como spring te obligue a exponer interfaces en vez de implementaciones es una buena noticia para tu servicio.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva de ayuda.